# Postgresql Syntax for a Left Join Throwing Syntax Error

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I have a `joa_clinics` table which has a field `grouper_id` and that field is reflected as `pcp_grouper_id` in a `joa_sales` table. What I need is to get all the values in the `joa_sales` table with an additional dynamic column `joa` which would be 0 or 1 depending on whether the `joa_sales` table has `pcp_gropuer_id` value as `null` or not. Here is my query so far but it generates a syntax error on the second select:

```
SELECT  *  FROM joa_sales, 
  SELECT CASE  WHEN  g.GROUPER_ID IS NOT NULL THEN  1  ELSE  0  END AS JOA
  FROM  joa_clinics exp   LEFT JOIN (   SELECT  DISTINCT GROUPER_ID    FROM joa_clinics ) g  ON exp.PCP_GROUPER_ID = g.GROUPER_ID;
```

Maybe I don't even need to reference the joa_clinics table but don't know the syntax. The above sql is copied from a SQL Server syntax but mine is a Postgresql server.

Thank you!

Comment: **Edit make** SELECT  DISTINCT GROUPER_ID    FROM joa_clinics

Comment: Omit the second `SELECT`.

Comment: I tried. Still get an error. But let me modify the query a bit more. Thanks.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax _everywhere_. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is I think will work for me. No Join was needed:

```
SELECT  * , CASE WHEN js.pcp_grouper_id IS NOT NULL THEN  1 ELSE  0   END AS JOA
FROM joa_sales js;
```